Langchain bedrock local integration test
I'm using Langchain to integrate with AWS Bedrock, with claude-3 model.
Is there a way to test my code locally, with a docker image or somegting?
I tried to use this one: https://github.com/aws-samples/sample-connector-for-bedrock?tab=readme-ov-file#llm-api, but it doesn't seems to have the right endpoints (e.g. it has /v1/chat/completions instead of /model/{modelId}/invoke), and also I couldn't find a way to inject the Bedrock localhost url into it.
It always uses this template: 'https://{service-name}.{region-name}.amazonaws.com'. In my case, in the integration tests I want it to use http://localhost:8866.
Any idea?
